# Limit objects in a collection from being serialized based on User

Tags: c#, entity-framework, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a webapi that returns an object that contains some collections of objects which also contains a collection of objects. Each of these objects has a bool that represents if the object is 'published' See classes below for general idea.

```
public class A {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public List<B> b { get; set;}
}

public class B {
  public List<C> c { get; set; }
  public List<D> d { get; set; }
  public bool published { get; set; }
}

public class C {
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public bool published { get; set; }
}

public class D {
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public bool published { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to make it so when I serialize any of these objects that an unpublished child objects are not included if the user doesn't meet the requirements, IE not in a specific role. Can I add data attributes to my model in some way? I have had a look into using a custom  `IContractResolver` but I'm not sure its the best way to handle the nested objects. Should I be handling this in the serializing stage or should I be removing the unpublished objects from the children after I get the object from the database.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to only load the data that is relevant to that users role, that way you don't have to worry about parsing it out at serialization time.

Comment: I didn't fully read to the end of your text- Do you have a reason to bring all the data down form the database? Presumable the only data required is the data for their role - unless you have some other reason to bring the data down from the db, I'd work on a solution that only queries for the data required.

Comment: Would you need any of the `unpublished` objects anywhere in your code besides other than the serialization stage?

Comment: I would not need any of the unpublished objects. I could look into only grabbing the published objects but with Entity framework I can't think of an easy method of getting for example an `A` with an `ID` of 2 and then ensuring that all B's are published and all C's and D's in those B's are published in a reusable way, hence why I thought I could do it at serialization settings globally for these objects. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you absolutely had to, you might consider adding a cloning method that does a deep clone of only the published items.  Though you should probably figure out how to make your ORM get only the data you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments (rightly) pointed out I was going about this in slightly the wrong way.

I solved my problems by having two database requests basic looks something like this.

```
A a = null;

if(User.IsInRole("Role")){
   a = db.A.Find(Id);
} else {
   a = (from a in db.A
        join b in db.B on a.ID equals b.ID
        join c in db.C on b.ID equals c.ID
        join d in db.D on b.ID equals d.ID
        where a.ID == id && b.Published && c.Published && d.Published
        select a);
}

if(a == null)
   return NotFound();

return Ok(a);
```

I was trying to avoid code like this but I'm not sure there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I would propose for a certain users to load only needed data as this will increase the performance. The case if you want to load all data (both published and unpublished) is trivial. For the user who may view only published items I would make such query:

```
A model = context.ACollection.Where(a => a.ID == id).Select(a => 
     new A { 
         ID = a.ID, 
         b = a.b.Where(i => i.published == true).Select(i => 
             new B{
                 published = true, 
                 c = i.c.Where(c_item => c_item.published == true),
                 d = i.d.Where(d_item => d_item.published == true)
             })
    }).Single();
```

This query should give you good performance.